# Would it really require 44 car batteries to heat my pool?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, electricity

After doing some research and math, I 'discovered' that it would take 44 (give or take 20%) car batteries to heat 1,000 gallon pool by 10 degrees.  Is this right or am I missing something?  It seems a little crazy!

- It takes 8.3 BTUs to heat one gallon of water 1 degree F.
- Thats 83,000 BTUs to heat the entire pool 10 degrees.
- A car battery holds [2,000,000 joules](http://muller.lbl.gov/teaching/physics10/old%20physics%2010/physics%2010%20notes/batteries.html).
- 2,000,000 joules is 1900 BTUs.
- 44 car batteries hold 38,600 BTUs.

Comment: I'm surprised it's that few batteries.

Comment: I make it 53 batteries, but I suspect that's the difference between a UK gallon and a US gallon.

Comment: Thats still an awful lot.  Also, my numbers are probably off by 20%

Comment: It will take more than 44 batteries once the water gets above ambient temperature. The heat will start to dissipate into the air.

Comment: @DavidZ : I have deleted the elements from my answer that made it complete. Please review and undelete.

Comment: @RijulGupta thanks, but we don't undelete in this circumstance. (The full answer is still accessible in the revision history.) Besides, your answer is still considerably more than I think is appropriate for a homework-like question.

Comment: @DavidZ : in my opinion any less will bring less than required understanding here. I personally learn more from examples than theorems and that is reflected in my answer. I am truly sorry that the OP or anyone else cannot benefit from it now.

Comment: @RijulGupta examples have their place in learning, certainly, but it's easy to facilitate cheating when you solve the given problem as an example. For the future, when you think an example would be useful, I'd suggest making up a different problem whose solution shares the essential characteristic that the OP is asking about, and show how to solve that. That way it will be very clear that you're not providing a complete answer to the question asked.

Comment: @DavidZ : will do that surely!

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia
`Average private pool length = 7.3m
 Average private pool breadth = 3.7m
 Average private pool depth = 2m`

This implies a top area of $27.01m^2$ and a volume of $54.02m^3$ which then means $54020 kg$ water.

emissivity of water is generally `0.98` Let your pool be $\text{t K}$ above ambient temperature. This would result in

$$P_{rad} = 5.6704\times 0.98 \times 27.01 \times t^4 \times 10^{-8}\text{ Watt}$$
$$P_{rad} = 1.501 \times t^4 \times 10^{-6} \text{ Watt}$$

At least this much power will be required to maintain the pool at desired temperature. This seems manageable.

Now to raise the temperature of pool by $\text{t K}$

`Specific heat of water is 4.187 kJ/kgK`
$$E_{req} = 54020 \times 4.187 \times t \text{ kJ}$$
$$E_{req} = 2.26181.74 \times t \times 10^5\text{ kJ}$$

number of car batteries having $2000 \text{ kJ}$ energy required would be

$$ \text{no. of batteries} = 113.09087 \times t$$

What you get with $44$ batteries, total energy = $88,000 \text{ kJ}$, how much water that heats to t K

$$m_{water} = \frac{8.8 \times 10^{4} \text{ kJ}}{4.187 \text{ kJ/kgK} \times t\text{ K}}$$
$$m_{water} = \frac{44901}{t} \text{kg}$$
$$vol_{water} = \frac{44.901}{t} m^3$$

Check for various temperatures yourself !

Note the amount of water $1000$Gallon if it were to be contained in a cube would be something like this

[image]

Clearly this does not look like a pool at all, maybe a hot tub or simply a bath tub.

Comment: An "endless" pool that is about 3 feet deep could use about 1000 gallons.